# does sqoop support dynamic partitioning with hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, bigdata

does sqoop support dynamic partitioning with hive? 
i tried using below-mentioned options : 
--hive-partition-key and --hive=partition-vlaue is only for static partitioning

for eg: 
sqoop import 
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/prac" 
--username root --password cloudera 
--hive-import 
--query "select id,name,ts from student where city='Mumbai' and \$CONDITIONS " 
--hive-partition-key city 
--hive-partition-value 'Mumbai'
--hive-table prac.student 
--target-dir /user/mangesh/sqoop_import/student_temp5 
--split-by id

Answer (score 1):

You can use hcatalog imports - you need sqoop 1.4.4 to do this.

```html
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:oracle:SERVERDETAILS" \
  --username <User Name>\
  --password <Password> \
  --table <Databse.Tablename> \
  --fields-terminated-by ',' \
  --split-by <Column Name> \
 --hcatalog-database <Hive DatabseName>
--hcatalog-table <Hive Table Name>
```

For more details please go through

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_hcatalog_integration